# Group by embedded field and count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection having documents with a field `"votes": [{id: "bob", vote: "yes"}, id: "mary", vote: "no"}]`. I want, for each person's `id`, how many documents they appear in with vote `yes`.

What I've tried so far is this, but it didn't work right; instead it seems to be grouping by the number of votes in addition to the ids.

```
db.votecol.aggregate([
    {"$group": {"_id": {"id": "$votes.id"}, "voteCount": {"$sum": 1}}}
])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator first since when it is applied on a list data field, it will generate a new record for each and every element of the list data field on which unwind is applied. It basically flattens the data so that you can process it as a single document in the preceding pipeline.

```
db.votecol.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$votes" },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$votes.id", 
            "voteCount": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

---

As an update to your follow-up question, you can filter the documents that are going through the pipeline to count votes that are "yes" or "no" using the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator before and after the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**. For bonus points, you can take advantage of using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step to evaluate the counts based on the embedded vote field value:

```
db.votecol.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "votes.vote": { "$in": ["yes", "no"] } } },
    { "$unwind": "$votes" },
    { "$match": { "votes.vote": { "$in": ["yes", "no"] } } },
    { 
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$votes.id", 
            "voteCount": { "$sum": 1 },
            "yesCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$votes.vote", "yes" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "noCount": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$votes.vote", "no" ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this only count votes that are "yes" or "no" but not anything else?

Comment: What is the difference between the match before the unwind and the one after?

Comment: The difference is by placing the `$match` stage at the start of a pipeline, the aggregation can use an index as well as query the collection to limit the number of documents that enter the pipeline. Because your aggregation operation requires only a subset of the data in a collection, the `$match` stage before `$unwind` will restrict the documents that enter at the beginning of the pipeline.After `$unwind` another `$match` is necessary in order to filter the documents from the flattened array.

Comment: It looks like the `votes.vote` isn't supposed to have a `$` preceding it (syntax error) -- removing it seems to produce the desired result.

Comment: @Hatshepsut My apologies, you are indeed right it's not supposed to be prefixed with $ and I've updated the answer.